# Asp .NET MVC. Generate mapping code at design time to map view model to domain object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mapping, automapper

I am working on a .net MVC project team in which we find ourselves writing pages of mapping code to map view models to domain objects and domain objects to DTOs (we consume java web services) and vice versa. Our architect has ruled out automapper due to performance concerns. We are left with dozens of "helper" classes to accommodate the mappings which have to be hand written and maintained. It is very cumbersome. What I would like is a tool to auto generate the mapping functions between the types with the power of automapper (with its convention based mapping etc) but at the design time. I cannot find one. Does anyone have any ideas? My hands are tied on using reflection based mapping tools like automapper. 
I appreciate any advise.
Thanks

Comment: Talk to the architect. His ruling is nonsense.

Comment: I don't think you will find something better than AutoMapper. In fact, after bootstrapping, AutoMapper is pretty fast, I used it in several projects and we did not ever have any perfo issues caused by it.

Comment: Thanks. I am in favour of introducing Automapper, however it is hard to argue for it when some measurements posted out there report a reduction in mapping performance between automapper and manual mapping by a factor of 7! [AutoMapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper]). I am looking at t4 to autogenerate the code but do not relish the challenge of writing complex algorithms to recognize _similar_ properties between the types e.g. CustomerID and Customer_ID.

Comment: Have _you_ measured a performance difference of 7 times?  AutoMapper actually generates the code to perform the mappings so should be virtually as quick as writing the code by hand (ignoring the initial one-off costs of generating the maps).

Answer (score 0):

Manual mapping is faster than any auto mapping framework. That said, AutoMapper is very fast. Yes it is slower when operating with a ton of data, but that is a limitation in .NET, not AutoMapper.

If I wanted to handle exceptionally large amount of data, I would use native code, (like c++), instead.

But, in most cases you will never encounter large amounts of data. Most of the "performance" tests made throughout the web, is made by itterating billions of objects to get a difference of a couple of seconds. So unless you really want to itterate billions of objects, don't discard AutoMapper. There is almost no trade off in day to day use.